# Box Shadow Ghosting in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, css

I am experiencing some ghosting, artifacting, or just general wonkiness when trying to use a box shadow on Internet Explorer 9.

The goal is to have a group of text areas, that when focused, will be highlighted with a box shadow. This is working without any issues in most browsers, but when cycling through elements in IE9, I see the following behavior:

[image: Box Shadow Example]

In the above example, the third text area loses focus to the second text area.  The left and right sides of the box shadow do not disappear on the third text area and do not appear on the second one.

The code to reproduce is below.  The issue appears when switching focus between the second and third text area.

**HTML**

```
<label>Text Area 1:</label>
<textarea class="sampleClass"></textarea><br /><br />
<label>Text Area 2:</label>
<textarea  class="sampleClass"></textarea><br /><br />
<label>Text Area 3:</label>
<textarea  class="sampleClass"></textarea><br /><br />
```

**CSS**

```
.sampleClass
{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}

.sampleClass:focus
{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(255,0,0,.8);
}
```

The code can also be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vfKEp/).

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: Wrapping them in a div http://jsfiddle.net/vfKEp/3/ or simply giving 'textarea' display: block http://jsfiddle.net/vfKEp/2/ seems to resolve the issue. This is still bizarre.

Answer (score -2):

I have a tip... in many cases we can use PIE!

http://css3pie.com/

it "makes Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features."

It helped me a lot!